# Cannot pass input value from view to component using #input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following component in html and I simply try to pass input value to the component:

```
<mat-accordion class="example-headers-align">
    <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="expanded" hideToggle>
      <mat-form-field *ngIf="expanded">
        <input #empName matInput type="text" formControlName="empName"/>
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
      <button *ngIf="expanded" mat-button (click)="add(empName.value)">Add</button>
    </div>
</mat-accordion>
```

However, the value is undefined in the component method and even I try to pass `empName`, instead of `empName.value` the parameter is also undefined. So, what is the mistake in this approach? How can I pass the input value without using `[(ngModel)]`?

```
add(data) { // data --> undefined
  this.add.emit(data)
}
```

I also get "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" error on `<button *ngIf="expanded" mat-button (click)="add(empName.value)">Add</button>`.

Comment: I did not mention this in my solution but there's an extra `</div>` that breaks your template there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

What you are doing is perfectly valid but you have not taken into consideration the scope of the template variables.

Using structural directives creates scopes/boundaries which block the usage of those variables, as you can see there: https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#template-variable-scope

So to solve your problem in the way you want you need to work on your template and remove the usage of the `*ngIf`s

#### A Partial solution

The following code which just omits the `*ngIf`s works as you'd expect it to *(naturally this is not a complete solution since your component without the `*ngIf`s just behaves differently from what you wanted)*:

```
<div>
    <mat-accordion class="example-headers-align">
        <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="false" hideToggle>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input #empName matInput type="text" formControlName="empName" >
      </mat-form-field>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
        <button mat-button (click)="add(empName.value)">Add</button>
    </mat-accordion>
</div>
```

You can check it out in this stackblitz project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-c64ppz?file=src/app/app.component.html (please ignore the console errors on the material components, those are not the point here :P)

#### A Possible Solution

One thing that would change your code in the smallest degree but allow you to keep your implementation could be to avoid the `*ngIf`s but hide the elements via css instead, as in the following:

Template:

```
<div>
    <mat-accordion class="example-headers-align">
        <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="expended" hideToggle>
            <mat-form-field [ngClass]="{'hidden': !expanded}">
                <input #empName matInput type="text" formControlName="empName" >
      </mat-form-field>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
        <button [ngClass]="{'hidden': !expanded}" mat-button (click)="add(empName.value)">Add</button>
    </mat-accordion>
</div>
```

css:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Again here's a stackblitz in which you can see it working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iamrut?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: My pleasure :) , I think it was important to explain why something which is a standard angular feature was just not working, instead of finding alternative ways to accomplish what you wanted. Anyway the scope I think is just the only tricky aspect of the template variables, so I believe it's good that you got to experience it first hand here :)

Answer (score 2):

**In your html file**

```
<mat-accordion class="example-headers-align">
        <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="expanded" hideToggle>
          <mat-form-field *ngIf="expanded">
            <input matInput type="text" [formControl]="empName"/>
          </mat-form-field>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
          <button *ngIf="expanded" mat-button (click)="add()">Add</button>
        </div>
    </mat-accordion>
```

**In your ts file**

```
empName = new FormControl('');

add() { // remove the parameter
  // this.add.emit(data), try if it is working first
     console.log(this.empName);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot, but actually I am looking for a solution without using `[(ngModel)]`. Is it possible?

Comment: @Fredrick I have editted the answer. check if it works.

Comment: Thanks, again I am wondering why is it not possible to pass a value easily? I am wondering if it is possible or not without using form control or ngModel.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `formControlName` with reactive forms, so if you want to access the value of this fields, then you have to access it from the `formGroup` form object.

Something like this:

```
employeeForm: FormGroup;
```

and the value of the form fields you can acess like this:

```
employeeForm.value.empName
```

So in your function try to pass value like this:

```
<button *ngIf="expanded" mat-button (click)="add(employeeForm.value.empName)">Add</button>
```